# MySQL Workbench copies Schema, but not data, from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration, mysql-workbench

I need to copy/migrate a database from MSSQL (SQL Server 2008) into MySQL. I am using the MySQL Workbench kit, and work through the process of the Migration. Each respective DB user has full access, the ODBC drivers are in place as well as the DSN.

It winds up copying the schemata successfully, but not any of the data. There are no errors or warnings (other than charset notices) and I am drawing blanks as to why data will not transfer over. There are not a lot of options in the migration steps, so I don't think I missed anything.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [**MySQL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard.html), the steps for the Migration Wizard should be

1. Connecting to the databases
2. Schemata Retrieval and Selection
3. Reverse Engineering
4. Object Selection
5. Migration
6. Manual Editing
7. Target Creation Options
8. Schema Creation
9. Create Target Results
10. **Data Migration Setup**
11. **Bulk Data Transfer**
12. **Migration Report**

Sounds like you got to Step 9. You have to make sure to setup Data Migration. Apparently, it is not automatic.

If you are having problems with the import, you are not alone. This has been a source of heartache for many. You may need to try :

- [**MySQL Migration Toolkit**](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=MySQLDeveloperSuite&v=1.1.10)
- [**SQLyog**](http://www.webyog.com/en/)

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bug.  I ran into the same issue and found the following bug report in my search for a fix: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66516

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial.

https://lalitvc.wordpress.com/2016/12/28/mssql-to-mysql-data-migration-using-mysql-workbench-6-3

I think, the problematic step for not copying data is in "**Data Migration Setup**". Please  select "*Online copy of table data to target RDBMS*".

Hopefully, your problem will be resolved.